# Как считать из файла текст Unicode C++

Tags: файлы, unicode, c++

Считываю текстовый файл, в котором символы могут быть как русские, так английские, да и вообще в Unicode

```
wifstream fs;
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
fs.imbue(locale());
fs.open(file);
wstring ws;
getline(fs,ws,L'\0');
fs.close();
```

Но вот проблема: вместо русских букв выводится всякие иероглифы. В отладчике VS 2010 то же самое. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В винде консоль использует для вывода кодировку cp866. Чтобы все было правильно, надо строку перевести в эту кодировку. Или сменить кодировку консоли. Или перейти на Линукс: там везде один сплошной utf-8 )))

Comment: Подождите. В какой кодировке ваш файл?

Comment: @VladD, а вот файл в utf-8. по крайней мере так написано в заголовке xml-файла

Comment: @Павел Воевода: [Исправьте пожалуйста](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/270287/edit) «Unicode» на «UTF-8» в вопросе (включая заглавие).